# .htaccess: deny access to operating system

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help please.
I want to deny access to my website by htcaccess by O.S.

I get it with windows using this code:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase Windows bad_os
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_os
```

But I want to deny access to Macintosh and Linux.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will block browsers running on Macintosh and Linux:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase Macintosh bad_os
BrowserMatchNoCase Linux bad_os
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from env=bad_os
```

check out http://www.useragentstring.com for other examples if you want to get more specific with your blocking

keep in mind it is trivial for a user to modify their user agent string to say whatever they want, so this will not be all that effective at actually blocking Mac and Linux browsers

Comment: thanks for the reply, now works!

I've get to block chrome and opera browser, but I can not with firefox and dolphin browsers.

    BrowserMatchNoCase Chrome CHROME
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=CHROME


BrowserMatchNoCase opera bad_browser
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_browser

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply, now works!

I get to block chrome opera browser, but I can not with firefox and dolphin browsers.

I use this code to deny Chrome and Opera:

> BrowserMatchNoCase Chrome CHROME
> Order Deny,Allow
> Deny from env=CHROME
>
> BrowserMatchNoCase opera bad_browser
> Order Deny,Allow
> Deny from env=bad_browser

Thanks again